# Wix 3rd Party msi pass command line parameters and switches

Tags: wix

was hoping somebody can shine a light on this for me.

I have a third party msi file that requires some switches and command line parameters and wanted to add this to a chain in a bundle as an MSIPackage element.

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="thirdparty.msi">
  Where do i pass switches to the msi? e.g. /c /y etc
  also wanted to supply some bootstrapper variables to the msi
</MsiPackage>
```

I noticed the EXEPackage has an install command where you could pass the relevant command line parameters but the MSIPackage does not.  All of the searches I have done, mention using MSIProperty but also imply they have control over the msi they are installing.

In addition to this, the msi property element requires a name and a value whereas a command line switch doesn't have a name.

I have a custom bootstrapper and wanted to set some variables which are then used as part of the MSIPackage.  The only solutions I can think of are:

1. call the command line and msiexec in the bootstrapper
2. use an exepackage and wrap the msi in an exe

just wanted to know if i'm missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: as I remember there must be something in MsiPackage for parameters. maybe it calls somehow strange. also, in your custom bootstrapper you can manage that sequence and run msi using internal bootstrapper engine. maybe you can pass parameters there. if not - your first solution looks great)

Comment: Have you tried googling for "MsiPackage arguments"? It seems that `MsiProperty` child element is used for this.

Comment: The MsiProperty requires a name so doesn't look like it supports command line switches.  I have used MSIProperties sucessfully for my own additional MSI but theres nothing that states if these get translated into command line parameters, i was also wondering if i could getaway with the sourcefile spec e.g. sourcefile="myfile.msi [wixvar1] [wixvar2]" but that doesnt seem to work and seems hacky in the first place.  Have tried googling this for quite some time but all that is mentioned is passing msiproperties to an msi you have build yourself